# Laravel Eloquent statement using inner join

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three models.

1. ScheduledMessage points to table scheduled_messages.
2. SubscribedService points to table subscribed_services.
3. SubscriptionServicesMsisdn points to table subscription_services_msisdn.

I have raw sql query that I would want to convert into eloquent but can not think of a way.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  b.message, c. phone_number, a.username, a.password from subscribed_services a 
inner join 
  subscription_services_msisdn c on a.id = c.subscribed_services_id 
inner join 
 scheduled_messages b on a.id = b.subscribed_services_id where DATE(b.scheduled_at) = CURDATE()
```

Would someone please help convert to eloquent.

**Relationship**

```
public function scheduled_messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ScheduledMessage::class, 'subscribed_services_id');
}

public function subscription_services_msisdns()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\SubscriptionServicesMsisdn::class, 'subscribed_services_id');
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you added any relationships to your models?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes... the relationship is there ...

Comment: In that can would you mind showing the relevant relationships you have in those models? Specifically for the `SubscribedService` model.

Comment: Why are you using `DISTINCT` in this query? It seems out of place.

Comment: @RossWilson I have updated with the relationships ...

Comment: @peterm I need Distinct query result. In the instance there are repeated rows.